# Android Drawable Image sizes

Tags: android, android-drawable

I want to add a png image to my app to be used as the background for a image button. Im not sure where put to it in my project hierarchy. Do i resize the image into the several different sizes, give them all the same name and place them into the drawable folder or do i create drawable folder for the different sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Check http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html to get a idea about resources use in different devices.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You can use the `9-patch-resizer` which generate the all of dimensions of your icon and create direct folders.

https://github.com/redwarp/9-Patch-Resizer

Or you can install Android Studio plugin `Android Drawable Importer` and in ScaledDrawable tab select your icon and generate resized icons directly in project.

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7658?pr=

Comment: Hi, Thanks very much for your answer. i have really been able to try this as i have seen to hit a major problem with my project :( i changed part of the name of the package. i changed one of the empty middle folder names. and also did the same in the grade.build and now my grade wont build and   I cant find the gradle.build file either